# «Няни, в корзину!» Грамотно ли оформлено предложение?

Tags: выбор-слов

«Няни, в корзину!» Грамотно ли оформлено предложение? Речь идет о том, что услуги нянь попали в список продовольственной корзины. В данном случае это заголовок к статье.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно. Реакция пишущего на составление "корзины" по-новому гротескным образом ассоциируются у него с новой обязанностью нянь буквально "полезать в корзину". Заголовок оформлен в повелительном наклонении: *"Няни, (полезайте-ка) в корзину!"*